# Ignoring global regex matchs if it is inside markdown code

Tags: regex, replace, markdown

In a markdown file, I am replacing the level links `./` with the URL `http://somesite.com` using `str.replace()` but I don't want this to happen inside of any **code block**.

I replaced it using `/[.]\//g`

OR

Ignored `../` with `/([.]\/)(?<![.]{2}\/*)/g`

This replaces every `./` with the URL, I don't want this to happen inside the **code block**.

#### target:

````
Work here:
[T](href="./somefile.ext") >> [T](href="http://somesite.com/somefile.ext")


Don't work here:
`href="./somefile.ext"` >> `href="./somefile.ext"`

Also not here:
```js
...
href="./somefile.ext"` >> `href="./somefile.ext"
...
```
````

Comment: @anubhava I don't want to replace `../` so ignored it as given in question and codes are written with backticks "`" they format code properly, which can have multiple lines so I am calling them code block.

Comment: Just info, your regex above is equivalent to `/([.]\/)(?<![.]{2}\/)/`

Comment: Generally, to skip a block would require a regex engine that can do balanced text then have a method of _SKIPing_ it. Perl or PCRE can do it easily. Even Dot-Net can do it. Sounds like you're using JS though which will have an inexact way, like `(\`{1,3})[\S\s]*\1)|<your regex>` This way requires a callback replace to see if group 1 matched and act appropriatly.